# Refrán: the shoemakers' children always go barefoot

Tags: traducción, modismos, refranes

Cómo se traduce exactamente esta expresión.
También estas otras, sé que existe una forma directa de decirlas en español:
-to be like a bull in a china shop
-what will be, will be
-An apple never falls far from the tree

Comment: UUUU yo me las sé, me las sé todas esas... pero voy a dejar que alguien se lleve la gloria... a ver quién es el que las adivina todas

Answer (score 1):

Algunas posibles versiones en español son:

- The shoemaker's children always go barefoot = En casa de herrero, cuchillo de palo
- to be like a bull in a china shop = ser como un elefante en un bazar
- What will be, will be = Lo que deba ser, será / Será lo que deba ser
- An apple never falls far from the tree = El fruto nunca cae lejos del árbol

Comment: Que será, será, see the song.

Comment: Never heard anyone say "qué será, será", which actually sounds awkward in real language.

Comment: Creo que ya pasó a la historia: https://cvc.cervantes.es/trujaman/anteriores/junio_04/21062004.htm

Comment: Para "An apple never falls far from the tree", en España se suele decir "de tal palo, tal astilla".

Comment: @wimi En América también se dice "de tal palo, tal astilla", pero más para "like father, like son". Me parece que "el fruto nunca cae lejos del árbol" tiene un sentido más profundo, como que el origen del comportamiento, bueno o malo, de alguien suele encontrarse en la familia de donde proviene.

Comment: En la Argentina también decimos ‘de tal palo, tal astilla’. La frase del árbol no la escuché nunca en castellano.

Comment: Otro más para "de tal palo, tal astilla", que refleja eso del comportamiento bueno o malo. Y el elefante suele estar en una cacharrería, aunque no se usa mucho.